# Pixel value extraction from a grayscaled image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, grayscale

I used the following function to extract rgb value from an image...but after gray scaling it. How can i find the pixel value of the image in python..

```
im = Image.open(s, 'r')
rgb_list= list(im.getdata())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use getpixel() function from PIL to obtain any pixel value, just by providing the pixel coordinates x and y.

```
<image_name>.getpixel(x,y)
```

If you are working in openCV then you can obtain the pixel values by-

```
pixel_value = <image_name>[x,y]
```

both the commands work for any type of color spaces.